# detect 15 minutes elapsed time from datetime.now

Tags: c#, datetime, timepicker

I have a timepicker and I wonder how I can make it detect if the selected time in the timepicker is 15 minutes ahead of the `DateTime.Now`.

If I set the timepicker to 9:15 and the `DateTime.Now` is 9:31 I should get a message that I only can set the time 15 minutes ahead the actual time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use TimeSpan ..

Assumed that your datetimepicker is TimeOnly ..

```
TimeSpan difftime = DateTimePicker1.Subtract ( now() );

if (difftime.Minutes > 15)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Max 15 Minutes !"); 
}
```

If your datetimepicker including date, so must ensure that `.Hours and .Days = 0`

Comment: `TotalMinutes`. Or `difftime > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)`

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
// In the timepicker's time-changed event
if (DateTime.Now.CompareTo(timepicker.Value) == 1 && DateTime.Now.Subtract(timepicker.Value).TotalMilliseconds > 15 * 60 * 1000)
{
     // Do stuff!
     MessageBox.Show("You can only set a max of 15 minutes ahead of the current time!");
     // Cancel the event / set the timepicker's value back to the current time / whatever you prefer
     // One option:
     timepicker.Value = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: I added some more text to my question before i got your answer

Comment: @RobinM I slightly modified the code for relevance but my answer is mostly the same. Please tell me if you have any trouble implementing it! (If you do, please say specifically what's going wrong)

Comment: I am getting to errors that are the following:
**The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.Subtract(System.TimeSpan)' has some invalid arguments** and the next error is:
**Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.TimeSpan'**

Comment: @RobinM - what are you using that you called 'timepicker'? I've been assuming a DateTimePicker object, which is the closest that I can find...

Comment: @RobinM oh wait, you seem to have made your variable nullable somehow. Possibly a .net 4.5 thing... er, add a `.Value` to the end of the argument to the `.Subtract` (What I have as `timepicker.Value`) - even if that means you have a `.Value.Value` - if that's no help, could you please post the code you're using? (Including any changes you made from what I wrote)

Comment: ... Actually, now that I think about it, `DateTime.Now` and `timepicker.Value` should probably be the other way around. Whoops!

Comment: Now i tried this: 
     if (DateTime.Now.CompareTo(endingTime.Value) == 1 && DateTime.Now.Subtract(endingTime.Value.Value).TotalMilliseconds > 15 * 60 * 1000) and I am getting this **An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred**

Comment: @RobinM - What is `endingTime`? is that a DateTimePicker object or...? (Also - where are you putting this code?) - It *should* be a DateTimePicker or similar object, and it *should* be in the Event raised when the value is changed -- for some reason, the `Value` of `endingTime` isn't set at all, so it gives that  error.

Comment: endingTime is a Timepicker. I am putting the code in the changevalue event for the timepicker. The endingTime is empty from the beggning.

Comment: Er... there isn't any object called a "Timepicker" that I can see. Again, the closest that I can find is "DateTimePicker" - is that it... or...?